# MPMoviePlayerViewController is not playing a video.

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using my local router to play the video. I have configured my router and attached pendrive with my router. the pen drive have some video files. I am getting a URL (i.e http://192.168.0.1/user/root/Sample.mp4) from router . When i open this url on web browser, Video is playing perfectly fine but when try to play the same url using MPMoviePlayerViewController or AVPlayerViewController its not working.

One interesting thing i observed that if i open the same url on iphone browser its not playing.

Please help me or give me a idea why its not playing on mobile app.

Comment: Make sure that your device connected to the same network of your web browser.

Comment: add App transport security in info plist

Comment: moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
 [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];
 [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];

Comment: We really need to see some code, or at least get some more information. e.g. are there any errors? Have you tried debugging at all?

Comment: @V12 Yes App transport security is enabled in info plist. Because rest of the GET and POST API calls are working fine for me.

Comment: @Imad yes i am sure by device is connected with same router.

Comment: @AllanPoole    moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerController];
    [moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];

Answer (score 0):

```
moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
 [player prepareToPlay];
player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerControll‌​er]; 
[moviePlayerController.moviePlayer play];
```

> add player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming; in your code

Edited

```
@property (strong, nonatomic ) MPMoviePlayerController*player;

   NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4"];

self.player  = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: movieURL];
[self.player prepareToPlay];
[self.player.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:self.player];


self.player.fullscreen = YES;
self.player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
self.player.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;
// player's frame must match parent's [self.view addSubview: self.movieController.view]; [self.movieController play];
[self.player play];
[self.view addSubview:self.player.view];
```

Comment: MPMoviePlayerController *player = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL: url];
    self.movieController = player;
    [self.movieController prepareToPlay];
    self.movieController.fullscreen = YES;
    self.movieController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault;
    self.movieController.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming; [self.movieController.view setFrame: self.view.bounds];  // player's frame must match parent's
    [self.view addSubview: self.movieController.view];
    
    [self.movieController play];

Comment: without playing the video its calling the moviePlayBackDidFinish notification method

Comment: Getting this error. Domain=MediaPlayerErrorDomain Code=-11850 "Operation Stopped" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped}

Comment: Hii @AbhayThakur, pls check i have edit my answer and its working at my end. so, pls try with edited answer

Comment: Its working fine when i load a video file from actual server. But my case is its not loading the video file from server. but loading from router pendrive. 
0
down vote
favorite
I am using my local router to play the video. I have configured my router and attached pendrive with my router. the pen drive have some video files. I am getting a URL (i.e http://192.168.0.1/user/root/Sample.mp4) from router . so the address http://192.168.0.1/user/root/EnglishMovies/Avatar/Avatar.mp4 is not the server address its mu router address.

Comment: "url on iphone browser its not playing" that means url not working on other devices instead desktop. is your desktop and iphone are connected with same wifi ?

Answer (score 0):

I had problem for playing video.I tried lot of ways but nothing helped.Then finally I went with below code.It works fine now.**I use iOS 10**.So **I use AVPlayerViewController as MPMoviePlayerViewController is deprecated**.

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) AVPlayerViewController *playerViewController;
- (IBAction)actionPlayVideo:(id)sender
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController (){
    NSURL *vedioURL;
}

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize playerViewController;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)actionPlayVideo:(id)sender 
{
    vedioURL = @"192.168.0.1/user/root/Sample.mp4"; 
    AVPlayerItem* playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:vedioURL];
    AVPlayer* playVideo = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:playerItem];
    playerViewController = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
    playerViewController.player = playVideo;
    playerViewController.player.volume = 0;
    playerViewController.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:playerViewController.view];
    [playVideo play];
}
```

Please check with your iPhone,iPad or iPod